# PHP code is being printed as HTML comments

Tags: php, html, comments

I am having the following piece of code in a php file:

```
    <?php
    include_once('includes/connection.php');
    include_once('includes/article.php');

    $article =  new Article;
    $articles = $article->fetch_all();
    ?>
<html>....</html>
```

Instead of getting the expected result, I get the message "fetch_all(); ?>, which means that the above code is treated as HTML comment. I have read the similar threads(that blame the short_open_tag value mainly) around but didn't help me at all. Any ideas?

Edit: Many thanks for your responses. Seems that the specific weird problem was about an update on my Linux system which messed up a little my permissions. I changed the user to http instead of root and the problem is gone.

Comment: a) is PHP installed? b) is the code in a .html or in a .php?

Comment: Remove all php code and put echo 'something'; to see if your problem is your PHP or something along with your article class or connection.php

Comment: Not really an HTML comment, I don't believe, just an odd or invalid opening tag. Anyway, what's your web server configuration? Server, OS etc?

Comment: `$article =  new Article;` should be `$article =  new Article();`. That's for sure. Apart from that, can you spot the whole "comment" in your html source and post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific problem was brought about by an update on my Linux system, which messed up my permissions a little. I changed the user in the Apache directory to http instead of root, and the problem is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is somewhere inside either `includes/connection.php` or `includes/article.php`. A line in there seems to indicate the start of the comment which goes all the way down to the `->` part.

Comment: Thought about that...but cant find anything suspicious in there

Comment: Does _any_ code execute? Can you spot the point up to which the script _does_ execute? If you create a simple script containing only `<?php echo "Hello there!";` and try to execute it, what will happen?

Answer (score 1):

In case you did not installed php. you might look at WAMP server. It includes php en mysql and works great on your local (windows) computer.

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y33pL/) your output?

Your code isn't being parsed by PHP and there might be several reasons for it:

- Check your URL. Does it look like you're fetching the file directly (`C:\Users\Name\...`) or are you going through your host `http://localhost/file.php`.
- Check your file extensions. Make sure it's **.php** and not **.html**.
- Check your server capabilities. Is PHP installed?

Comment: Yeah, that's the output. To answer your questions: It is through localhost, the extenstion is .php and php is installed.